# UICollectionViewController can't scroll when it's in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

When I put `UICollectionViewController` with vertical scroll in `UIPageViewController`, Sometimes my ``UICollectionViewController' can't scroll and forced at top, even crashed without any error message.

I want to show a media collection for photos and videos separately, support swipe gesture between two segments.

[[image: This is what I want to do[1]]

Comment: Show your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Now I solved this problem:

**I use `UIViewController` with a property of `UICollectionView` instead of using `UICollectionView` directly**

My `UICollectionViewController` was reused by two `UIPageViewController` Seems that `UICollectionViewController` dealloc its `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` before release itself, so reuse this class may cause the problem.